# node running server throw Error regarding already runinng port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 8082

}

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8082

Comment: This means another application using this port . you need to change the port

Comment: no need to change the port , kill the other port

Comment: There must be some another application running on that port. Either you choose another port to run your aplication or kill the process on that port and then run again.

Comment: Yeah Exactly, thatswhy i am posting this question .

Comment: @RAMANASSVV, if the port 8082 is used by other application , killing the process is not the right option. because you can't  run both programs simultaneously. Another possibility same program rung and it crashes and the port not free, in this case killing the port is the best option.

Comment: @RAMANASSVV, if the port 8082 is used by other application , killing the process is not the right option. because you can't  run both programs simultaneously. Another possibility same program rung and it crashes and the port not free, in this case killing the port is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

First findout your processID for your running process

***lsof -i:1234(your port ID)***

COMMAND     PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    55523 ssurisettii   42u  IPv6 0x53ab9cb514809733      0t0  TCP localhost:53991->localhost:us-cli (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    55523 ssurisettii   45u  IPv6 0x53ab9cb51480d473      0t0  TCP localhost:53989->localhost:us-cli (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    55523 ssurisettii   46u  IPv6 0x53ab9cb514809d53      0t0  TCP localhost:53990->localhost:us-cli (CLOSE_WAIT)

this ways shows,

Now you kill the your related processID

suppose your port id contains processID 1234

then **** kill -9 1234 ***